# Create rewriterules for different domains in htaccess file with WP multisite

Tags: multisite, htaccess, rewrite-rules, domain-mapping

Normally if you have one WordPress website it is easy to create rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file for your domain. For example, if your domain is DomainA.com and you have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^i-like-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ wp-content/themes/customtheme/custom-pages/ilike.php?like=$1 [L]
```

You will get DomainA.com/i-like-...

But what if I have a multisite with the following domains:

- DomainA.com (primary domain)
- DomainB.com (Mapped domain)
- DomainC.com (Mapped domain)

And I want to create a rewrite rule for DomainB.com for a specific file like above?

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to target a specific domain then you need a *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive), preceding the `RewriteRule` that checks for the specific domain (`Host:` header). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainb\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^i-like-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ wp-content/themes/customtheme/custom-pages/ilike.php?like=$1 [L]
```

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains just the `Host:` header sent in the request.

Reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Awesome, thanks MrWhite! Searching for this for quiet a while..